# Gitlab pipeline fails when using rsync to upload to staging server

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, pipeline, rsync, sshpass

I'm currently using the Gitlab Pipelines to upload everything to my server.

The .gitlab-ci.yml path for uploading to the staging folder looks like the following:

```
staging_upload:
  stage: staging
  only:
    refs:
      - develop
      - schedules
  script:
    - sshpass -V
    - sshpass -p '$FTP_PASSWORD' rsync --progress -avz -e ssh . $FTP_USERNAME@$HOST:$PATH
```

While executing the pipeline I get the following error:

```
Using "assword" as the default password prompt indicator.
$ sshpass -p '$FTP_PASSWORD' rsync --progress -avz -e ssh . $FTP_USERNAME@$HOST:$PATH
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

I already tried out various things but none we're working.
Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: The "no such file or directory" response would seem to indicate that rsync is not actually installed in the gitlab runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hope this this [article](https://codeburst.io/gitlab-build-and-push-to-a-server-via-ssh-6d27ca1bf7b4) helps, I have not used rsync but scp should do the work.
- gitlab secret variable can be used for USER_PASS

```
script:
    - export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r directory-to-copy user@host:path-to-copy-files-to
```

Comment: Maybe it is important to say that the `-o stricthostkeychecking=no` does most of the trick. As `scp` can use different known_hosts file from `ssh` it can be reason why you get very confusing message: `no such file or directory`.